# Dropdown Calculate in real time

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, calculator

This is my form I want to after submission package and event id calculate with sum and guest field is always calculate (guest value * 5) then total result show in `<div id="result">`. How can I do that? and this result set in `id="totalprice"` value. Thanks

```html
<form action="" class="myform" method="post" id="calculate">
  <h1>Reservation Info</h1>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" placeholder="Date">
  <select name="event" id="event">
    <option id="50" value="event 1">Event 1</option>
    <option id="150" value="event 2">Event 2</option>
    <option id="300" value="event 3">Event 3</option>
    <option id="500" value="event 4">Event 4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="guest" placeholder="Number of gests" />
  <h1>Packages</h1>
  <select name="package" id="asdasd">
    <option id="100" value="100">Package 1</option>
    <option id="200" value="200">Package 2</option>
    <option id="300" value="300">Package 3</option>
    <option id="400" value="400">Package 4</option>
  </select>

  <div id="result">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" id="totalprice" />

    <h1>Additional comments</h1>
    <textarea rows="4" name="comment" placeholder="Additional comments"></textarea>

    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please edit your question. I created a snippet. Now you can add what you tried in the JavaScript pane of the editor when you click "Edit this snippet" - Also change the names/IDs from "event" and "submit" to something else since they are reserved words and a name of "submit" will hide the form submit event - lastly give each option a "Please select" option

Comment: @rayan005 Please add the JS part that you have tried for this.

Comment: @Nishesh Pratap I cant do real-time calculation code. I have only ajax submission code. Could you write code for me

Answer (score 0):

For calculating total price you need to create a JS function and then you need to call that function on change of guest, event and package field.

Below is the snippet where we have created a JS function **calculateTotal()** and in that function we are calculating the sum of all 3 fields. Please change calculation logic as per your need.

```
<form action="" class="myform" method="post" id="calculate">
  <h1>Reservation Info</h1>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" placeholder="Date">
  <select name="event" id="event" onchange="calculateTotal()">
    <option id="50" value="50">Event 1</option>
    <option id="150" value="150">Event 2</option>
    <option id="300" value="300">Event 3</option>
    <option id="500" value="500">Event 4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="guest" name="guest" placeholder="Number of guests" onchange="calculateTotal()"/>
  <h1>Packages</h1>
  <select name="package" id="package" onchange="calculateTotal()">
    <option id="100" value="100">Package 1</option>
    <option id="200" value="200">Package 2</option>
    <option id="300" value="300">Package 3</option>
    <option id="400" value="400">Package 4</option>
  </select>

  <div id="result">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" id="totalprice" />

    <h1>Additional comments</h1>
    <textarea rows="4" name="comment" placeholder="Additional comments"></textarea>

    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
<script>
function calculateTotal(){
var guest = parseInt(document.getElementById("guest").value);
var event = parseInt(document.getElementById("event").value);
var package= parseInt(document.getElementById("package").value);
var sum= event+package+(guest*5);
document.getElementById("totalprice").value=sum;
}
</script>
```